# Is what I understand of PowerShell Approved Verbs correct?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to the PowerShell universe and I just came across a warning in VS that said I wasn't using the *"Approved Verbs"*. So I googled that and found [the whole list of approved verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428.aspx) for user-defined commands.

However, some quite similar verbs are given a quite different meanings in this list. So, I've tried to summarize the differences; what I need to know is whether my understanding of those differences is accurate or not.

#### `Get` vs. `Find` vs. `Search`

`Get-*` retrieves a **precise** something (i.e. an *object*, a *resource*, a value... Anything that can be represented by a *POCO* in PowerShell and .NET) from a given container of things. It takes a relatively **short** time.

`Find-*` **tries** to retrieve something from a given container of things. It takes a relatively **long** time.

`Search-*` **tries** to retrieve a **reference** of something from a given container of things. It takes a relatively **long** time.

---

#### `Select`

`Select-*` **extracts or transforms** from its input to produce some differently structured output. Think of it like the [Linq's Select clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx).

Depending on the parameters it's been given, `Select-Object` can act as a filter like `Where-Object`, through `Where-Object` is much lower level.

---

#### `Get` vs. `Read` vs. `Receive`

`Get-*` retrieves data from an **resource** (e.g. a file, an object, an environment variable).

`Read-*` retrieves data from the **console** or the **pipeline**. The notion of [stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.stream.aspx) isn't very far.

`Receive-*` retrieves data **asynchronously** (e.g. from the network).

---

#### `Set` vs. `Write` vs. `Send`

`Set-*` **amends** the data of a resource (e.g. a file, an object, an environment variable).

`Write-*` produces and **displays** data on the console or the pipeline. Writing data is a **final outcome**.

`Send-*` issues data **asynchronously** (e.g. over the network). Sending data is only a first step, this data will be **acted upon later**, likely by another process.

---

#### `Write` vs. `Out`

`Write-*` **produces** some output.

`Out-*` **redirects** the output of a pipeline. Think of it like Bash's redirections (e.g. `> /dev/null`, `>> /var/log/cake.log`).

---

#### `New` vs. `Add`

`New-*` makes up a **brand new something**, likely empty or in a default state.

`Add-*` appends data to **an existing something**.

---

#### `Add` vs. `Register`

`Add-*` **appends** data **to a something**.

`Register-*` creates a **record about something** in a container (e.g. a database).

---

#### `Initialize` vs. `Install`

`Initialize-*` performs the **first configuration** of something.

`Install-*` sets something up when it **wasn't there before**. `Install` is higher level than `Initialize`: it can be seen as `{ New | Move | Copy } + [ Initialize ]`.

---

#### `New` vs. `Install`

`New-*` **makes up** a brand new something, **likely in a default state**.

`Install-*` **puts an existing something** in the right place. It may also **configure** it by the way. `Install` is higher level than `New`: it can be seen as `{ New | Move | Copy } + [ Initialize ]`.

Comment: This isn't really a question..?  The verbs are all semantic and no one can tell you with certainty whether you're using the right one, it's a judgment.  If you're going to distribute functions/cmdlets, yes, you should use `Get-Verb` and use one off that list, otherwise it really doesn't matter.

Comment: This is a good attempt at comparing the approved verbs and their usage, but I have to agree that it's not a question and doesn't really belong here. It would make a good blog post, or perhaps a forum discussion, so I would encourage you to find a place to publish it where it would be better received.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Wasn't this list intended to bring this _certainty_?

Comment: @Odepax There are (at least) two very differing possible ways to interpret the question of whether your understanding is accurate, and I'd summarize them as "Is my understanding of the *Microsoft's intention* accurate" and "Is my understanding of *the current real life use of verbs among users* accurate". The answer to the first question is "yes, your understanding seems faily accurate", the second one is a very different question, and not one that's necessarily a useful contribution on a QA site :)